# Preload all the images on AJAX Fancybox request

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a link that triggers an AJAX call to display in a Fancybox. The page to display contains images. I would like Fancybox to wait (spinner) while all the images are loaded without showing the Fancybox.

Is there a way to do this?

The page that makes the AJAX request does not have access to the URL of the images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to have some sort of div load with some spinner image in the fancybox.

Then use `.load(url, callback() { });`, and within the callback function, hide the loading div once the content has finished loading.

```
$('#fancyWindow').load('whatever.html', function () {
    $('#loadingSpinner').hide();
});
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is that I'll have 2 different load screens, the one where the Fancybox AJAX request is completing, and the one where the images are loading. It would have been nice for the user not to see any difference between the 2